# Connect to an already running instance of chrome using selenium in python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am facing an issue with chrome while launching it with extensions using selenium. I have logged an issue
https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=508

For a workaround I am planing to launch chrome than enable required extension, after this connect to it using selenium.

But I am unable to so so.
Can anyone help in this matter as d=webdriver.Chrome() always launches a new chrome instance.
I want to connect to an already running instance of chrome.

Answer (score 8):

**Reconnect to a driver in python selenium **
This is applicable on all drivers.
1. open a driver

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

2. extract to session_id and _url from driver object.

   ```
   url = driver.command_executor._url       #"http://127.0.0.1:60622/hub"
   session_id = driver.session_id            #'4e167f26-dc1d-4f51-a207-f761eaf73c31'
   ```

3.Use these two parameter to connect to your driver.

```
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url,desired_capabilities={})
    driver.session_id = session_id
```

4. And you are connected to your driver again.

   driver.get("http://www.mrsmart.in")

Comment: I'm using Chrome and this just opens up another window.

Answer (score 6):

This is simply not possible in Selenium, in any browser and in any programming language.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18

Comment: well that link mentions that it's not possible 'cos chrome would have to be started in a particular way.But if it were startd in a particular way  e.g. chrome with --remote-debugging-port,   then it should be technically possible

Answer (score 3):

Now it is,

1. Fire up the java server
2. Hit localhost:4444/wd/hub
3. Create a session for the appropriate browser
4. Create a remote webdriver client using the given session ID (syntax may vary depending on language bindings you are using)

reference: [github issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/915)

Answer (score 0):

You can, it's covered here

[what does "add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")" actually do when added to Options() on Python? Selenium related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70704413/what-does-add-experimental-optiondebuggeraddress-localhost8989-actuall)

So e.g.

If you do

(adjust the command for your needs, your chrone path.. and the user profile you want to use).  chrome://version can show you the chrome user profile folder for whatever chrome user.

```
C:\Users\User>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --remote-debugging-port=8989 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\User\App
Data\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3"

C:\Users\User>
```

Then in your python program

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
selclient = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
selclient.get("http://www.dogpile.com")
```

That python code will not launch a new chrome window.  It will connect to the already existing chrome instance that you started from eg the command line.