# Ruby - Program navigator module

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir

I have a Ruby program that uses a webdriver (Watir) to walk a page and perform tests alongside a BDD suite called RSpec.

I'm trying to optimize it for a slow server by improving its ability to navigate efficiently. Thus far It has been creating a new browser session for each test package, then closing it afterwards. This is very inefficient because it hits the login page again for every instance. 
Of course, I don't want to hard-code navigation instructions into the tests because adding new spec files may change the order they are executed in, and not every page of the webapp has the main navigation bar, so navigation may need to change based on the page the last spec left the browser on.

I need some kind of master library or module that will take what page the program is at and what page it wants to go to, then bring the browser to that page so it can begin testing. What is the best way to do this?
I'm not fantastically experienced so I'd love input from more seasoned developers. Should I have each page be a class? Should I just stick with closing browsers after each test packet? Should I manually code brute-force methods (gotoPage1FromPage2)?
Okay, that last one was a joke. Seriously though, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not sue about watir, but in selenium it may be possible to connect to an existing browser session. That way you could run the browser process in a separate terminal and connect with your apps as needed. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721404/connect-to-an-already-running-instance-of-chrome-using-selenium-in-python for some python code which should be translatable to Ruby since Selenium uses mostly the same API for all it's packages. Alternatively you can look at [selenium standalone server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: Please don't use session ids to reuse browser instances. This is absolutely not supported by the Selenium team and is a bad idea in almost all circumstances. Use your test runner the way your test runner is designed to be used.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you have a lot of general questions that are less suited to Stack Overflow. Feel free to join the Watir Slack channel (part of the Selenium Team Slack): http://seleniumhq.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are exactly correct about the difficulties of maintaining state in  your tests. Shutting down a browser between each session is the best way to make sure that you always know the state of the browser at all times for a test. Saucelabs goes so far as to spin up a new virtual machine for each of the tests they run. Ideally you decrease test time by running multiple tests in parallel.

I'm  not certain I know what you mean by "test package" or how many times that means you are starting a new browser and logging in, but... another thing to consider investigating is whether you can set a cookie or use oauth to log in without having to use the navigation. I've worked at places that allowed admin logins for their staging environments by passing a parameter in an url.

Your tests should be clear in their intention, which typically means your Page Object implementation does not know about what comes before or after the actions you are taking. You should be able to look at the RSpec code and reproduce exactly what it is testing. Abstracting methods for taking you from one place to another magically in the background is not a good idea.

Best practice used to be having methods from one Page Object return new Page Objects. So users could write methods like this in their tests: `LoginPage.new.login.view_account.edit_address`. Many of us have been bitten by this approach. Plus it isn't as easy to read as doing something like this:

```
LoginPage.new.login
HomePage.new.view_account
AccountPage.new.edit_address
```

This doesn't prevent you from using `#visit` methods as needed to navigate between Page Objects.

Comment: My current implementation has been to define attributes of each page in a class (elements, for instance) using a hash (like link(:ok, id: 'ok_button')) then instantiating an object to represent that page. The end result is a DSL resembling 'dashboard_page.ok' or 'login_page.user = "Joe"'. I'm just about ready to begin integrating the optimizer portion into this functionality, but you seem to be indicating this is a bad move. Can you elaborate on why abstracting navigation methods is a bad idea?

Comment: You should avoid reinventing this wheel and use one of the Page Object gems. We're just starting to have a larger discussion in the Watir community about doing a better job of integrating page object code with Watir. I'm going to be biased toward mine (https://github.com/titusfortner/watir_drops), but Alex has a great one that makes good use of Watir (https://github.com/p0deje/watirsome/), and the most popular one is Cheezy's (https://github.com/cheezy/page-object), but  due to some design limitations it does not support everything that Watir does.

Comment: I already have been using Cheezy's page-object gem. My question is more about how to integrate additional inter-page navigation functionality with my program. I only recently discovered pages-as-objects gem solutions recently, so in the context of the main question this would have been very helpful (so you're on the right track)