# Attach an existing web browser to automate using Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, browser

Upon doing this code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
...

var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());

// To automate...
// driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.example.com/");
```

I'm getting this error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Unexpected error.
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4444

1. Will doing that code attach the existing Firefox browser to automate or what?
2. How can I fix the error?

   - [Reconnect to a driver in python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32882207/4883372)
   - [Selenium WebDriver in C#: How to use the existing window of Chrome Browser.](http://www.binaryclips.com/2016/03/selenium-webdriver-in-c-how-to-use.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have selenium server running with all appropriate selenium web drivers available.

http://localhost:4444/wd/hub is a service run by the selenium server component. You send commands to selenium server and then it executes them using the appropriate webdriver.

Have a read here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#webdriver-and-the-selenium-server

Comment: So downloading *selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar* is necessary?

Comment: Yes. You need to download that and run the jar. You also need the appropriate webdriver for your browser (on the same download page)

Comment: Do you mean, by doing this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32882207/4883372 in Python with http://127.0.0.1:60622/hub will also require you the *selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar* ?

Comment: No. All you need to do is, have java installed, then in a .bat file enter `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar` and save it in the same directory and run it. Also place the WebDriver in the same directory

You do not need python. The error you have is because the program on that .jar file is not running so it can't connect "No connection could be made..."

Comment: @5ervant I have previously written an article about this on my wiki 

[https://github.com/NattyMan0007/NUnitDocs/wiki/Selenium-Server-Configuration](https://github.com/NattyMan0007/NUnitDocs/wiki/Selenium-Server-Configuration)

Comment: Yes, I already understand now that to be able to use `RemoteWebDriver()` you need the *selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar* running.. So to be able to attach an existing browser to automate you still need that server, but they're looks heavy to apply on a Windows app 'cause Java is also required.