# what does "add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")" actually do when added to Options() on Python? Selenium related

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, localhost

I'm trying to figure out what's the difference between opening a chrome driver with the following option `add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")`:

```
##chromeoptions
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=os.path.join(sys.path[0]) + "/chromedriver.exe",
    chrome_options=opt,
)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

And opening the same chrome driver but without any option:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=os.path.join(sys.path[0]) + "/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

In what stuff does `add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")` affect the deployment of the driver?

Comment: There's a debugger in Chrome that you can hook into "remotely"...  when chromedriver launches the browser in devmode I think it'll hook into to this... to use the wire protocol to send/receive commands to/from the browser?  Setting the port explicitly is not necessary...chromedriver will get/set that from the browser when's its launched in devmode (along with the sessionID) I think people use this if they are trying to connect to a previously opened browser that had set a specific port for the remote debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Basic answer, im newbie with this)**

Using:

```
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
```

You can execute selenium scripts on already opened browser.
See this video and you easily understand:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zrx8FSEo9lk&t=432s&ab_channel=Mukeshotwani


**While using the second option, the script open a new browser and run the commands.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot I had asked this question, I ended up realizing that as you claim, by adding `opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")`  (and having run a chrome browser `--remote-debugging-port=8989` on cmd),  Selenium can take control of the browser for doing any task or process.